# Force download an image from src using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I've an `image` tag with a parent div which contains `image_wrap` class. Now I want to download this image using javascript. I've got some solution to download this image, but this code is not working for me. Can anyone help me please?

**Here is my code:**

```js
var img_wrap = $('.image_wrap'),
    src = img_wrap.find('img').attr('src'),
    anchor = '<a href="' + src + '" download></a>',
    downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(anchor);
    
downloadable_tag.click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_wrap">
    <img height="100px" width="200px" src="https://s3.envato.com/files/248564292/01_eduma.__large_preview.__large_preview.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by download via JavaScript? Offer it as a downloadable file to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems there in your code.

First, you are appending the wrong element to `img_wrap` element. You should be appending the `anchor` element instead of the `downloadable_tag`.

Then, `.click()` should be used on dom objects, not on Jquery objects. So I think you should fix that line too.

Finally, the `download` attribute will show the download window only for files which are in the same domain. It doesn't work for cross origin requests for security purposes.

So with all the mentioned fixes, this is how your code should be:

```
<div class="image_wrap">
    <img height="100px" width="200px" src="01_eduma.__large_preview.__large_preview.jpg" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var img_wrap = $('.image_wrap'),
        src = img_wrap.find('img').attr('src'),
        anchor = $('<a href="' + src + '" download>hello</a>'),
        downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(anchor);

    anchor[0].click()
```

Notice that I have used a **local path** for the image. Here's a plunker demo.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eK1yJTYPUzF5p4DVTRem?p=preview

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts!

Answer (score 0):

Try following script:
http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/8928/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

var img_wrap = $('.image_wrap'),
src = img_wrap.find('img').attr('src'),
anchor = '<a href="' + src + '" download>hello</a>',
downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(anchor); 
downloadable_tag.trigger('click')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to download the image rather than navigating it. The attribute `download` works only for same origin URLs. Check documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the same variable in the append statement

`downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(downloadable_tag);`

Change it with the below one.

`downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(anchor);`

```js
var img_wrap = $('.image_wrap'),
    src = img_wrap.find('img').attr('src'),
    anchor = '<a href="' + src + '" download>hello</a>',
    downloadable_tag = img_wrap.append(anchor);
    
downloadable_tag.click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_wrap">
    <img height="100px" width="200px" src="https://s3.envato.com/files/248564292/01_eduma.__large_preview.__large_preview.jpg" />
</div>
```